# System,is my solution right?

Tags: number-theory

Solve the system:

[image]

That's what I have tried:

The system is equivalent to this one:

[image]

$$\text{We set: } M=5 \cdot 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11,M_1=154,M_2=385,M_3=110,M_4=70$$

We solve the following:

- $$ 154x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$
  $$4x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$
  $$x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$
  $$\xi_1=2$$
- $$385x \equiv 3 \pmod 2$$
  $$x \equiv 3 \pmod 2$$
  $$\xi_2=3$$
- $$110x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
  $$5x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
  $$x \equiv 6 \pmod 7$$
  $$\xi_3=6$$
- $$70x \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$$
  $$4x \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$$
  $$x \equiv 1 \pmod 11$$
  $$\xi_4=1$$

We set $\displaystyle{ c=M_1 \xi_1+M_2 \xi_2+M_3 \xi_3+M_4 \xi_4=2193}$

So, $$x \equiv 2193 \pmod{770} \Rightarrow x \equiv 653 \pmod{770}$$
Therefore, $x \equiv 653+770q, q \in \mathbb{Z}$

Could you tell me if it is right or if I have done something wrong?

Comment: $2x \equiv 3\pmod{5} \implies x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, not $3$.

Comment: Oh,sorry!!! I accidentally wrote it like that...It is $$2x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
I edited my post...could you tell me if it is right now??

Comment: The answer is correct.

Comment: Nice,thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking

$653 \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 2$

$653 \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 5$

$653 \equiv 2 \text{ mod 7 }( 630 + 21)$

$653\equiv 4 \text{ mod } 11 (550+99 +4)$

Therefore yes.

Comment: How did you find that $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ ?

Comment: thanks Ethan, and 653 ≡ 1 mod 2, because it is odd

Comment: But how did you get this? You found the second,third and $4^{th}$ parity by replacing $653$ at the system,right? But,how did you find the first one?

Comment: Your x≡3 mod 2 is the same as x≡1 mod 2, just evaluated once more :), is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes,you are right!!!! Yes,that's what I am asking!!! Thank you very much for your answer!!! :D